# Extending Components with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Let's say I have a Foo component with some React Router navigation:

```
var Foo = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (<div>
            <Link to="/foo/1">1</Link>;
            <Link to="/foo/2">2</Link>;
            {this.props.children}
        </div>);
    }
});
var Foo1 = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <p>foo 1</p>;
    }
});
var Foo2 = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <p>foo 2</p>;
    }
});
ReactDOM.render((
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" ...>
            <Route path="foo" component={Foo}>
                <Route path="1" component={Foo1} />
                <Route path="2" component={Foo2} />
            </Route>
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('main'));
```

Now let's say I also have a Bar component, which is very similar (except, well, `bar` instead of `foo`). In a "classic" React application, I would have "extracted" the common logic out, like so:

```
var Element = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (<div>
            <Link to={this.props.url + '/1'}>1</Link>;
            <Link to={this.props.url + '/2'}>2</Link>;
            {this.props.children && React.cloneElement(this.props.children {
                name: this.props.name // Ugly hack to propagate props...
            })}
        </div>);
    }
});
var Element1 = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <p>{this.props.name} 1</p>;
    }
});
var Element2 = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <p>{this.props.name} 2</p>;
    }
});
var Foo = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <Element url="/foo" name="foo" />;
    }
});
var Bar = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <Element url="/bar" name="bar" />;
    }
});
```

As you can see, I've *almost* got it (even that ugly props propagation hack...). The part I'm missing is how to define the routing itself:

```
ReactDOM.render((
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" ...>
            <Route path="foo" component={Foo}>
                <Route path="1" component={?} />
                <Route path="2" component={?} />
            </Route>
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('main'));
```

I mean, there are no longer `Foo1` and `Foo2` components, because Foo has an `Element`, from which they are generically derived. I could, of course, explicitly define `Foo1` to have an `Element1` and `Foo2` to have an `Element2`, but then I would have to implement `Foo` instead of letting the `Element` do it for me; or maybe I could pass the components themselves as props (i.e. `Foo = ... <Element ... component1={Foo1} component2={Foo2} />`... but then what?).

So: how can I achieve this kind of React-ious "inheritance via composition" with React Router on? Or is there another way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

I thought of a solution, so I thought I'd post it for people with a similar problem. Please note I'm still new to this.. uh.. "mindset", so it might not be the best possible way.

Here's the thing: The foo/bar difference (`url="/foo|/bar"` and `name="foo|bar"`) can be "summed" into a single `"foo|bar"` tag, which can then be extracted into the URL as a *parameter*. That is:

```
ReactDOM.render((
    <Router>
        <Route path="/" ...>
            <Route path="/:tag" component={Element}>
                <Route path="/:tag/1" component={Element1} />
                <Route path="/:tag/2" component={Element2} />
            </Route>
        </Route>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('main'));
```

And the elements can be rewritten to take that tag into account:

```
var Element = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (<div>
            <Link to={'/' + this.props.params.tag + '/1'}>1</Link>;
            <Link to={'/' + this.props.params.tag + '/2'}>2</Link>;
            {this.props.children}
        </div>);
    }
});
var Element1 = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <p>{this.props.params.tag} 1</p>;
    }
});
var Element2 = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return <p>{this.props.params.tag} 2</p>;
    }
});
```

And that's it! You don't even need the `<Foo />` and `<Bar />` components.

The reason I'm not perfectly happy about this solution is that it works for a simple enough case (like this example, or the actual CMS I'm working on), but I'm not sure it scales to more complicated designs; that, and there's the URL clash: a `/baz` route with a `<Baz />` component must appear first, otherwise an `<Element />` with the `"baz"` tag would be evaluated instead. I still haven't found how to define complex parameters (like regular expressions) with React Router, but if I do, I'll update the answer.